# file not found in node js (Intellij)

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea

I am using node js express. I  am trying to access a text file located in the same directory of that js file. So the file structure goes like this

```
- ProjectFolder
  |
  - many modules and folders
  - routes
    |
    - Index.js
    - input.txt
```

The Simple code that i have tried is ,

```
var data = fs.readFile('~/IdeaProjects/Title/routes/input.txt');
console.log("Synchronous read: " + data.toString());

console.log("Program Ended");
```

I did try different paths but nothing works. for your information, I am using fedora as os.

The error i got was,

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '~/IdeaProjects/Title/routes/input.txt'
at Error (native)
```

Any suggestion about how to access that file so that i can both read and write the contents of the file , will be welcomed. Looking for detailed answer.

Comment: You have a file `Input.txt` and you're using `input.txt` in the code.

Comment: Besides the error in path, you have a bug in code. `readFile` is async function, so you can't get result without callback. In your case it should be - `readFileSync`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node doesn't interpret some characters that have special meaning like `~` or shell variables like `$HOME`, so you will need to use something like `path.resolve()` to get an absolute path or use a relative path (e.g. `IdeaProjects/Title/routes/input.txt`).

Also, as @Gothdo pointed out, there is a discrepency in the filename which will cause issues on case-sensitive file systems.

You will also need to either change `fs.readFile()` to `fs.readFileSync()` or add a callback to `fs.readFile()` like so:

```
fs.readFile('~/IdeaProjects/Title/routes/input.txt', function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Synchronous read: " + data.toString());
  console.log("Program Ended");
});
```

Comment: Is this fine ?? fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('~/IdeaProjects/Foodie/routes','../input.txt'));

Comment: i used the filereadsync code from the previous comment and i get a error like,path is not defined. Why is that?

Comment: If you're using `path.resolve()` you have to add a reference to the `path` module first: `var path = require('path');`.